# Synapse External table issue

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have this error yhen i do a select in a external table (it's ok when i see the data review debug result in the dataflow synapse)
error :
Column 'ASSET_TYPE_CODE' of type 'INT' is not compatible with external data type 'Parquet physical type: BYTE_ARRAY, logical type: UTF8', please try with 'VARCHAR(8000)'. File/External table name: 'refine_table.FOREX_EOD'.

Comment: Try this for a work around. It did solve my problem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/895544/sql-error-when-querying-parquet-table-added-to-lak

Answer (score 1):

- The error message you received indicates that there is a mismatch
  between the expected data type of the '**ASSET_TYPE_CODE**' column in
  your external table and the actual data type found in the Parquet
  file.
- The data in the Parquet file for the 'ASSET_TYPE_CODE' column is
  stored as a byte array representing **UTF-8** encoded characters.

Here you can find more about [types supported](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/types/).

Here is how you can do a select in a external table.
[image]
**SELECT Query:**

```
SELECT  CAST(ASSET_TYPE_CODE AS  VARCHAR(8000)) AS ASSET_TYPE_CODE, OTHER_COLUMN_1, OTHER_COLUMN_2
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK  'https://<xxxxxxxx>.xxxx.core.windows.net/xxxxx/xxx.Table_asset.parquet',
FORMAT='PARQUET'
) AS [result];
```

[image]

Or

```
select  *
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK  'https://xxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/xxxxxx/xxx.Table_asset.parquet',
FORMAT='PARQUET'
) AS [result];
```

[image]